# Remove Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, uninstallation, centos6

I installed Zend Framework through composer but I don't want it Later. 
It's in my `/public_html/store2/zf/` folder. 
I tried removing the `/public_html /store2/` folder, but in seconds it comes back.

Comment: do you want to remove entire zend server?

Answer (score 1):

Composer installs its dependencies into vendor directory.

```
vendor/zendframework
```

Not into the public directory.

Are you sure it is composer putting it back & not version control?

What do you mean,

> in seconds it comes back

, what command are you running?